# ruby gem 'google_drive' - No such file or directory - gcloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-drive-api

I've created a new Rails 5.2, Ruby 2.5.3 Application and using [gem 'google_drive'](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby)

Whenever I call the following command

```
@session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_config("config/google-config.json")
```

I get a log message

> No such file or directory - gcloud

I have not had this problem with past applications and am wondering what is going on.

Comment: You do not have command line helpers from google sdk (aka `gcloud`) installed / available on the path. Ruby code is just a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

@Aleksei, you were correct, I needed to install [gcloud on ubuntu](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu)